# How to find the principal point in an image?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I need to find the principal point in an image. Its a point where the principal axis intersects the image sensor.
Due to misalignment this point is not at the center of image always(or image sensor). I need to precisely determine its location using any of the optical methods available(if any). Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

More information: The camera is giving me a live feed over a screen and I am able to store, analyze any part of it in real time or later.

[image]

Comment: Depends highly on what the image is!

Comment: It must only depend on the arrangement. The principle axis always goes through to the center of the lens and perpendicular to it and hence hits the same point always.

Comment: Really need answer for this one. My work is stuck up because of this question

Answer (score 2):

To do this you would need to take an image of some sort of reference object, like a regular grid pattern. You would also have to know that your imaging system has some measurable field aberrations which are radially symmetric, such as distortion. Then you could do some simple image processing to locate the center of the distortion pattern.

In the case of a regular grid pattern, you would plot the positions of the grid lines in the image. With third order distortion, the grid lines should be spaced quadratically (ie. with the space between each grid line increasing linearly). The grid spacing will reach a max (or min) at the "principal point." (I use scare quotes around "principal point" because the principal point has a specific meaning in geometrical optics, and it is not the meaning used in the question here.)

Comment: @Colin wont it require me to place this pattern perfectly parallel to the camera?

Comment: @bubble: Well, the pattern should be pretty close to perpendicular to the optical axis, but small errors won't have a large effect on your results. The magnitude of the error in your measurement would go like the cosine of the angular alignment error, which means that for small angles it doesn't vary much at all.

Comment: @Are you suggesting to detect the maxima manually or programmatically. It will be nice if i dont have to write a program.

Comment: @bubble: I guess it depends how accurate you need to be. Usually this is not a critical piece of information for most imaging systems, but it depends on what you are doing with it. If you are doing research grade astronomical observation, you will generally need to calibrate your camera in **great** detail. If you just want to make some simple measurements, it is generally enough to know that your imaging system has relatively low distortion.

Comment: @Colin while trying to do as suggested the effect of distortion is so less that I am not able to locate the distortion center manually.

Comment: @bubble: Then it sounds like you've just proven that your imaging has low enough distortion that it doesn't matter if the sensor is exactly centered on the optical axis. :)

Comment: @Colin I need the location of that point to do some geometric alignment. I dont know how the low distortion helps in that.

Comment: @bubble: The location of the optical axis only matters if you have significant field aberrations. If you've looked at a grid image and you cannot detect any aberration, then you have directly proven that you do not need to know where the optical axis lies.

Comment: @Colin I need this point for alignment of the camera. Presence or absence of aberrations have no say in it. If I know the principle point then I will turn the camera so that its reflection(camera center) from a mirror falls at this principle point, making it perfectly perpendicular to the wall

Comment: Perpendicular to the wall? If you want to image a wall with accurate geometry, the most important thing is to have the sensor parallel to the wall, which may not be the same as having the optical axis perpendicular to it. Stick the grid on the wall, image it again and swing the camera horizontally until the top and the bottom grid lines are imaged parallel, then tilt it vertically until the leftmost and rightmost lines are parallel.

Comment: @Edgar do you mean to say that optical axis may not be perpendicular to the image sensor? In that case the image will be blurred for most of its part. I mean that should never happen, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I do not know how good your camera is. ;-) If it was perfect, then you would not question its optical axis going through the very center of the sensor, would you? A small misalignment may not have a visible impact on the image quality anyway. Large misalignments are sometimes used in photography for controlling the orientation of the plane of best focus, either using [tilt-shift lenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt-shift_lens) or the movements of a [view camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_camera).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest shining a narrow laser beam along the optical axis. Just don't fry your sensor! Hopefully, the antireflective coating of the lens is not perfect, and you will be able to see on the object side **two** reflections of the beam: one from each side of the lens. Align the laser in such a way that both reflections come back exactly at the output port of the laser: the beam is then perpendicular to both faces of the lens, and therefore it is exactly along it's optical axis.

Now look at the image: you have one bright spot exactly at the focus.

Comment: This works in principle, but depends on a lot of assumptions about the imaging system. If it has multiple elements, and the assembly tolerances aren't very tight, the results could be far from correct. It also requires that the aperture be large enough that a pencil beam down the center can be large enough to avoid severe diffraction effects.

Comment: As soon you try fire a laser on a camera nothing is visible. Even a very small diffracted portion of light knocks out the sensing ability completely. We see all white image.

Comment: I must say a very intelligent reply. But it wont work

Comment: @bubble: Well, if the only problem is the laser being too bright for the sensor, then you could, after the alignment, dim it with some filter, like an Hoya ND400 (400x), a B+W ND3.0 (1000x) or a pair of crossed polarizers.